# Resizing my Table or Window? HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Trying to get my application to fit into the browser window both width and height keeping proportions.

I have included a JS fiddle of an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/4Mjtr/3/

Was sliced in photoshop so the way the html is output is each div class has its own css e.g

```
 //HTML//
<div class="id1462-Select-Pattern">
 <a href="Patterns.html"><img src="http://www.travel-master.co.uk/coach-hire-minibus-images/email-quote.jpg"width="183" height="45" alt="" /></a>
</div>

//CSS//
div.id1462-Select-Pattern {
    position:absolute;
    left:80px;
    top:723px;
    width:183px;
    height:45px;
 }
```

I have tried media queries but the canvas and images dont seem to resize also i read that with text you have to manually change the font size but the images are not resizing properly

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Height from the image, setting only the width will resize the image and keep proportions as well.

You can use javascript function to get the browser's Width & Height, would be something like:

```
function getBrowserWindowSize() {
    var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
    if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
        //Non-IE
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
    else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    }
    else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        //IE 4 compatible
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }

    var currWindow = new Array();
    currWindow[0] = myWidth;
    currWindow[1] = myHeight;
    return currWindow;
}
```

And you can manage your desired elements width & height with the resize and load events by calling this function again.